# Can't get Annual Salary to Print. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: java

I can't figure out how to get the annual salary to print out at the end of the code.

I have tried all sorts of configurations, but it ultimately leaves it off of the printout. I know it's likely a simple mistake, but can't figure it out. What the heck am I doing wrong?

```
package AverageSalary;

public class Employee {
    //private variables for Employee Name and Monthly Salary.
    private String employeeName;
    private double monthlySalary;

    // Constructor that initializes name and monthly salary
    public Employee(String EmployeeName, double mnthSalary) {
        employeeName = EmployeeName;
        monthlySalary = mnthSalary;
    }

    //set Employee Name function
    public void setEmployeeName(String employeeName) {
        this.employeeName = employeeName;
    }

    //get Employee Name Function
    public String getEmployeeName() {
        return employeeName;
    }

    //monthlySalary
    public void setMonthlySalary(double monthlySalary) {
        this.monthlySalary = monthlySalary;
    }

    public double getMonthlySalary() {
        return monthlySalary;
    }

    // Method named annualSalary returns the salary for a whole year.
    public double annualSalary() {
        return getMonthlySalary() * 12;
    }

    // toString method that returns a string containing the name and monthly
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("\nEmployee Name: %s, Monthly Salary=$%,.2f", 
            getEmployeeName(), getMonthlySalary(), 
            annualSalary());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add Annual salary to the format `String`; you currently only include Employee Name and Monthly Salary: Something like

```
return String.format("\nEmployee Name: %s, Monthly Salary=$%,.2f, "
        + "Annual Salary=$%,.2f", getEmployeeName(), getMonthlySalary(), 
        annualSalary());
```

Comment: Wow, that is exactly what I had tried before, but it didn't work for me. I must have missed a quotation or something. Thank you so much for your assistance!